# Docker CLI exit status 1

Tags: windows, docker, desktop

I did a self-diagnosis of Docker Desktop on my windows machine using this command:
`PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources> & "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.diagnose.exe" check`
However, when I ran that command the output says that the docker CLI has failed as shown below:

```
[2024-03-06T17:31:52.075700900Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] ipc.NewClient: eac00204-diagnose -> \\.\pipe\dockerBackendApiServer BackendAPI
[2024-03-06T17:31:52.094461600Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (5348cc14) eac00204-diagnose C->S BackendAPI POST /idle/make-busy
[2024-03-06T17:31:52.099463100Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (5348cc14) eac00204-diagnose C<-S 4ea4775e-BackendAPI POST /idle/make-busy (5.0015ms): 0xc00068c350
[2024-03-06T17:31:53.105229400Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (7390f093) eac00204-diagnose C->S BackendAPI GET /idle
[2024-03-06T17:31:53.107848000Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (7390f093) eac00204-diagnose C<-S 4ea4775e-BackendAPI GET /idle (2.0165ms): {"apisInFlight":{"/_ping":30,"/containers/json":4,"/images/json":5,"/v1.43/info":1,"/v1.43/version":1,"/volumes":4},"booted":true,"busyReason":["11 container(s)","in-flight APIs: map[/_ping:30 /containers/json:4 /images/json:5 /v1.43/info:1 /v1.43/version:1 /volumes:4]","timed activities: map[/idle/make-busy:28.9897555s]"],"containers":11,"idle":"bool","kubernetesEnabled":false,"reduced":false,"services":0,"timedActivities":{"/idle/make-busy":"float64"},"vmPaused":false,"vmRunning":true,"vmStopped":false,"windowsContainers":false}
[PASS] DD0027: is there available disk space on the host?
[PASS] DD0028: is there available VM disk space?
[SKIP] DD0002: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled?
[SKIP] DD0018: does the host support virtualization?
[PASS] DD0001: is the application running?
[SKIP] DD0022: is the Virtual Machine Platform Windows Feature enabled?
[SKIP] DD0021: is the WSL 2 Windows Feature enabled?
[PASS] DD0024: is WSL installed?
[PASS] DD0025: are WSL distros installed?
[PASS] DD0026: is the WSL LxssManager service running?
[PASS] DD0029: is the WSL 2 Linux filesystem corrupt?
[PASS] DD0035: is the VM time synchronized?
[PASS] DD0017: can a VM be started?
[PASS] DD0016: is the LinuxKit VM running?
[PASS] DD0011: are the LinuxKit services running?
[PASS] DD0004: is the Docker engine running?
[PASS] DD0015: are the binary symlinks installed?
[PASS] DD0031: does the Docker API work?
[PASS] DD0013: is the $PATH ok?
[FAIL] DD0003: is the Docker CLI working? exit status 1
[PASS] DD0005: is the user in the docker-users group?
[PASS] DD0038: is the connection to Docker working?
[PASS] DD0014: are the backend processes running?
[PASS] DD0007: is the backend responding?
[SKIP] DD0009: is the vpnkit API responding?
[PASS] DD0010: is the Docker API proxy responding?
[SKIP] DD0006: is the Docker Desktop Service responding?
[SKIP] DD0030: is the image access management authorized?
[PASS] DD0033: does the host have Internet access?
[PASS] DD0002: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled?
[PASS] DD0018: does the host support virtualization?
[PASS] DD0001: is the application running?
[PASS] DD0022: is the Virtual Machine Platform Windows Feature enabled?
[PASS] DD0021: is the WSL 2 Windows Feature enabled?
[PASS] DD0024: is WSL installed?
[PASS] DD0025: are WSL distros installed?
[PASS] DD0026: is the WSL LxssManager service running?
[PASS] DD0029: is the WSL 2 Linux filesystem corrupt?
[PASS] DD0035: is the VM time synchronized?
[PASS] DD0017: can a VM be started?
[PASS] DD0016: is the LinuxKit VM running?
[PASS] DD0011: are the LinuxKit services running?
[PASS] DD0004: is the Docker engine running?
[PASS] DD0015: are the binary symlinks installed?
[PASS] DD0031: does the Docker API work?
[WARN] DD0032: do Docker networks overlap with host IPs? network docker_public has subnet 172.26.0.0/16 which overlaps with host IP 172.26.96.1

Please note the following 1 warning:

1 : The check: do Docker networks overlap with host IPs?
    Produced the following warning: network docker_public has subnet 172.26.0.0/16 which overlaps with host IP 172.26.96.1

If the subnet used by a Docker network overlaps with an IP used by the host, then containers
won't be able to contact the overlapping IP addresses.

Try configuring the IP address range used by networks: in your docker-compose.yml.
See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address


Please investigate the following 1 issue:

1 : The test: is the Docker CLI working?
    Failed with: exit status 1

The Docker CLI is needed to build, share and run applications.
```

I checked both the Docker Desktop Service and the Docker Engine and they both say they're running.

At the OS level, it is Windows 10 Pro with WSL 2 activated and virtualization at the BIOS level activated.
Last time I restarted, I was installing a bunch of Windows features.

I tried to reboot my machine, but I still cannot access the Docker command line.